# PHP email form sends email everytime page is refreshed

Tags: php, forms, email, refresh

my php email for is sending emails every time the page is refreshed. For example the user is filling out the form and sending it with the send button. That's all fine and good but if they refresh the page it sends the email again with all the same form info.

I believe this is the problem code but don't know what it is.

```
    require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = 'WebForm';
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $body = $_POST['message'];
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    // $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    // print_r($_POST);
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Host = "smtp.office365.com";
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->Username = "person@emailaddy.com";
    $mail->Password = "password";

    $mailto = "person@emailaddy.com";
    $mailfrom = "person@emailaddy.com";
    $mail->SetFrom($mailto, '');
    // $mail->AddReplyTo($mailfrom, 'email');
    $address = 'person@emailaddy.com';
    $mail->AddAddress($address, "My Addy");

    $mail->Subject  = $subject;
    $mail->AltBody  = $body;
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
   }
```

Comment: check out this image http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f3/PostRedirectGet_DoubleSubmitProblem.png

Comment: You're best redirecting to another page with header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a header instead and make sure you have no output before header.

```
if(!$mail->Send()) {
    header("Location: http://www.example.com");
    exit;
    }
```

If that does not work for you, use a meta refresh method:

```
if(!$mail->Send()) {
$to = "http://www.example.com";
    $url = $to;
    print "<meta HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT=\"0; URL=$url\">";
    exit;
}
```

or display a message and redirect after 5 seconds:

```
if(!$mail->Send()) {
$to = "http://www.example.com";
    $url = $to;
    print "<meta HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT=\"5; URL=$url\">";
    print "Thank you for your message.";
    exit;
}
```

---

**Edit:** (cookie/token method)

You can use a cookie and this is just an example.

```
<?php

$token = time();
setcookie('formToken', $token, time() + 3600);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if($_POST['token'] != $_COOKIE['formToken']){
// die("Sorry");

$error_list .= '<li>You can not submit this form twice.</li>';

echo $error_list;

echo '
Thank you, your message has been sent. You do not need resubmit it again.
';

exit;

}

    foreach( $_POST as $values ) { $data .= $values . "<br>"; echo $data; }

}

?>

<form action="" method="POST">  

Name: <input type="text" name="name">
<br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I was hoping to output the success message on the same page as the form. I'm new to programing is that against better practices? Like is it considered improper coding to output success message on same page as form?

Comment: @user3770278 It's not "improper" but you will still have the same problem. You can add `exit;` or `exit("Thank you");` after your `echo 'Message has been sent';` but that will make your form disappear. I suggest you redirect them to your home page instead or the form itself which comes up to the same thing really, or use Ajax.

Comment: @user3770278 If they refresh the page using `exit;` after the echo, you will still have the same problem. It's best to redirect to another page.

Comment: @user3770278 Another thing you can try is adding `unset($_POST);` after `echo 'Message has been sent';` but that may not be the best method. Even a cookie or captcha would help.

Comment: @user3770278 I've added a cookie/token method you can base yourself on. Try it out, and hit refresh. You will see the result. Reload under **Edit**

Comment: Thanks very much for the speedy answers. I would upvote if I had sufficient rights

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = 'WebForm';
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $body = $_POST['message'];
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    // $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    // print_r($_POST);
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Host = "smtp.office365.com";
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->Username = "person@emailaddy.com";
    $mail->Password = "password";

    $mailto = "person@emailaddy.com";
    $mailfrom = "person@emailaddy.com";
    $mail->SetFrom($mailto, '');
    // $mail->AddReplyTo($mailfrom, 'email');
    $address = 'person@emailaddy.com';
    $mail->AddAddress($address, "My Addy");

    $mail->Subject  = $subject;
    $mail->AltBody  = $body;
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
}
```

the `mail` sending function was outside of the if condition with `$_POST` check. So it was sending mail everytime it is refreshed.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the super fast response. Even with the send mail function inside is still sends with every refresh. I changed the above code to reflect that.

Comment: try with `var_dump($_POST)` and see what it is getting on every refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You should use different files, at different URLs to handle the actions:

- send email
- display confirmation page

For example:

**In your form**

```
<form ... method="post" action="/sendmail.php">
```

**In sendmail.php**

```
// same code as above except:
if(!$mail->Send()) {
    header("Location: success.php");
} else {
    header("Location: error.php");
}
```

[See the doc for details](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

**In success.php**

```
<p>Oh yeah ;)</p>
```

**In error.php**

```
<p>Ooops :(</p>
```