# Modal contact form. Email submitting whenever refresh page. Unable to get error messages to appear.

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Hullo. I am trying to make a modal appear on my website that will let people who visit send messages to an email i have designated. I am completely new to coding and have spent many hours trawling these forums for help. I followed this tutorial: https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/working-bootstrap-contact-form/.

This is my html:

```html
<div class ="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog"> 
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="contact.php"> 
     <div class="modal-header">
      <h4> Contact </h4>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="contact-name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input name="nameinput" type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" placeholder="First & Last Name">
          <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'> $errName </p>";?> 
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="contact-email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input name="emailinput" type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
          <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?> 
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="contact-message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
          <textarea name = "messageinput" class="form-control" id="contact-message" rows="4"></textarea>
          <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMsg</p>";?>  
         </div>
       </div>
     </div> 
     <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="human" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> 2 + 3 ? </label>
        <div class = "col-sm-10">
         <input type = "text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="Type your answer here">
          <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errHuman</p>";?>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
         <!-- will be used to display an alert to the user -->
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
      <div class = "form-group">
       <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
      </div>
```

This is my php:

```html
<?php 
  $errName='' ;
  $errEmail='';
  $errMsg='';
  $result='';
  $errHuman='';

  //have to define variables outside of if statements, even if you just set them to null or ''//

  
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
   $name = $_POST['nameinput'];
   $email = $_POST['emailinput'];
   $message = $_POST['messageinput'];
   //$human = intval($_POST['human']);
   $from = 'From: $name';
   $to = 'danroebuck1994test@gmail.com';
   $subject = 'Message from Contact Form';
     
   $body ="From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
  
   

 
  
   // Check if name has been entered
   if (!$_POST['nameinput']) {
    $errName = 'Please enter your name'; 
   }

   // Check if email has been entered and is valid
   if (!$_POST['emailinput'] || !filter_var($_POST['emailinput'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
   }

   //Check if message has been entered
   if (!$_POST['messageinput']) {
    $errMsg = 'Please enter your message';
   } 

   //If there are no errors, send the email
   if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMsg) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Email sent successfully')</script>";
    } else {
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert ('An error occurred, the email has not been sent. Please try again later.')</script>";
    }
   //}
  }
?>
```

The first trouble I am having is that when I open up the modal by pressing the contact button, the red text is not displaying below the fields to ask for the required inputs. 
The second issue is that whenever I refresh the page, the previous email I set up in the form is sent lol, with the alert popping up saying 'your email has been sent successfully'. This seemed very weird to me as I thought using the if(isset($_POST["submit"])) would mean it would only be sent if the submit button was clicked.

I ask for any assistance possible. I did search these forums for a solution and I found this: [PHP email form sends email everytime page is refreshed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26749537/php-email-form-sends-email-everytime-page-is-refreshed). However I did not find it helpful to me. As this was 6 hours ago and I have now made no progress I figured it would be reasonable to ask. Thankyou friends.

Comment: Are you running your website on the server or locally?

Comment: locally i tihnk it is. with Xampp

Comment: why you put so many `<div class="modal-body"></div>` seriously? you can use bootstrap Grid system for better control over HTML elements and they will be responsive and will look much better on different screen sizes

Comment: Thanks I'll do that in the future.